# Haystack and Solr- Schema Parsing Failed

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to rebuild_index, but after building the schema ( manage.py build_solr_schema ) I copy and paste the output in the schema.xml file. After restarting the server and rebuild_index ( manage.py rebuild_index ) I'm getting the below error. I've been trying to get the problem, yet no success! What I'm I missing? Should I first delete the XML codes in the schema file before pasting the new one?

```
  HTTP Status 500 - Severe errors in solr configuration. Check your log files for more detailed information on what may be wrong. If you want solr to continue after configuration errors, change: <abortOnConfigurationError>false</abortOnConfigurationError> in solr.xml -------------------------------------------------------------
  org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: No cores were created, please check the logs for  errors at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize    (CoreContainer.java:172) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:96) at
  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:277) at   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:382) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:103) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4649) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5305) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:650) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1582) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 
  ------------------------------------------------------------- org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Schema Parsing Failed: Attribute name "omitN" associated with an element type "fieldtype" must be followed by the ' = ' character. at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:688) at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.<init>(IndexSchema.java:123) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:481) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:335) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:219) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:161) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:96) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:277) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:382) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:103) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4649) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5305) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:650) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1582) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run (Unknown Source) Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Attribute name "omitN" associated with an element type "fieldtype" must be followed by the ' = ' character. at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException  (Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError  (Unknown Source)   at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanAttribute(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument  (Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:159) at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:418) ... 24 more       ------------------------------------------------------------- org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Attribute name "omitN" associated with an element type "fieldtype" must be followed by the ' = ' character. at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException (Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError (Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError  (Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanAttribute(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) at org.apache.solr.core.Config.<init>(Config.java:159) at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:418) at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.<init>(IndexSchema.java:123) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:481) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:335) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:219) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:161) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:96) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:277) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:382) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:103) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4649) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5305) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:899) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:875) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:650) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1582) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The Schema Output

```
        <?xml version="1.0" ?>
        <!--
         Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
         contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
         this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
         The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
         (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
         the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

           http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

          Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
         distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
         WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
         See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
         limitations under the License.
         -->

         <schema name="default" version="1.4">
           <types>
            <fieldtype name="string"  class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true"   omitNorms="true"/>
            <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/>
            <fieldtype name="binary" class="solr.BinaryField"/>

            <!-- Numeric field types that manipulate the value into
              a string value that isn't human-readable in its internal form,
             but with a lexicographic ordering the same as the numeric ordering,
             so that range queries work correctly. -->
           <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0"     omitNorms="true" sortMissingLast="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
          <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" sortMissingLast="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
          <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" sortMissingLast="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
          <fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" omitNorms="true" sortMissingLast="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

          <fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
          <fieldType name="tfloat" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
          <fieldType name="tlong" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
         <fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

         <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
        <!-- A Trie based date field for faster date range queries and date facetin. ->
       <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true"  precisionStep="6" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

       <fieldType name="point" class="solr.PointType" dimension="2" subFieldSuffix="_d"/>
       <fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate"/>
       <fieldtype name="geohash" class="solr.GeoHashField"/>

       <fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
       <analyzer type="index">
       <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"  enablePositionIncrements="true" />
       <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
       <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
        -->
       <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
       </analyzer>
       <analyzer type="query">
       <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
       <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignore Case="true" expand="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
     </fieldType>

     <fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">

      <analyzer type="index">
       <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords_en.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
      <!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
      <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/> -->
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
       <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords_en.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
        <!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
      <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/> -->
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      </fieldType>

      <fieldType name="text_ws" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">

      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
     </fieldType>

     <fieldType name="ngram" class="solr.TextField" >
         <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
     </analyzer>
     </fieldType>

     <fieldType name="edge_ngram" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="1">
     <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1"  generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0"  splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1"   generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0"  splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
     </analyzer>
     </fieldType>
     </types>

     <fields>
      <!-- general -->
      <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true"/>
      <field name="django_ct" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
      <field name="django_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"  multiValued="false"/>

      <dynamicField name="*_i"  type="int"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
      <dynamicField name="*_s"  type="string"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
      <dynamicField name="*_l"  type="long"   indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
      <dynamicField name="*_t"  type="text_en"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
      <dynamicField name="*_b"  type="boolean" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
      <dynamicField name="*_f"  type="float"  indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
      <dynamicField name="*_d"  type="double" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
      <dynamicField name="*_dt" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
      <dynamicField name="*_p" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
      <dynamicField name="*_coordinate"  type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="false"/>


      <field name="text" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

      <field name="price" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

      <field name="city_stay" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

      <field name="guideline" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

      <field name="state" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"  multiValued="false" />

      <field name="address" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"  multiValued="false" />

      <field name="pub_date" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />

      </fields>

      <!-- field to use to determine and enforce document uniqueness. -->
      <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>

      <!-- field for the QueryParser to use when an explicit fieldname is absent -->

      <defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>

      <!-- SolrQueryParser configuration: defaultOperator="AND|OR" -->
      <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>
      </schema>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't run Solr, hence can't test this, but a few problems jump out at me (more accurately, are flagged as errors when I try to prettyprint the XML :-) )

- line 40 (`<!-- A Trie based date field ...`) ends in `->`; should be `-->`
- line 59 (`<filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" ...`) contains `ignore Case="true"`; should be `ignoreCase="true"` (no space in attr name)

If you fix these errors, it will most likely solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks... will try it. I've switched to whoosh and it's working. Don't know why Solr is giving me headache.

Answer (score 1):

Django Haystack only supports Solr 3.5+

http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backend_support.html#id1

If you're using Solr 1.4, the schema format has changed between 1.4 and 3.5

Comment: This is the issue. Very frustrating, as the only real solution is to install Solr 3.5 from scratch, which is a nightmare.